# PHP mt_rand return same number every time

Tags: php, random

random.php

```
$min=1;
$max=13031;
$ran_num = mt_rand($min,$max);
echo $ran_num;
```

This is working fine on my local host, but when I run it on my server, it always return the same number. not sure what is going on.

Update:
I am running a wordpress site, and I put the random.php in the theme folder.
I also have eaccelerator installed, this might be the issue, I am looking into it now

Comment: What number does it return each time? Are you salting with mt_srand() at all?

Comment: Since 4.2, you shouldn't have to seed anymore.

Comment: @mdsl - the interesting thing about seeding: if you seed with the same value every time, you'll get the same sequence of random numbers returned every time

Comment: I am always getting 7078. but on localhost, I get different number all the time, I need it to return a random number from a range.

Comment: @MarkBaker Sure, but shouldn't PHP seed with a different number every time? That's how I understand the documentation.

Comment: @mdsl - If you do seed with a different number each time, then you will get a different sequence each time; but it all depends if you need to create a repeatable random sequence.... there are times when seeding with a known value may give a required behaviour (stacking the deck). http://ideone.com/fb9dVu creates 10 random numbers.... I predict that you'll get 1049, 
11221, 
8211, 
12440, 
6357, 
4567, 
12376, 
9225, 
12455 and  
6877

Comment: @MarkBaker I believe that I get your point. I do understand the importance of seeding a PRNG - my point is that it should not matter to someone using mt_rand after 4.2 as "[t]he random number generator is seeded automatically."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server has PHP lower than 4.2 - you need to call to [mt_srand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php) before you can use mt_rand

Comment: also, if your php version is lower than 4.2 then holy crap, update your shizz

Comment: PHP 4.2 still exists?!

Comment: Yes, even php 3 can be found sometimes (good news - very very rare) :)

Comment: I have PHP 5.2 installed

Comment: @JayChen then it is no related to seed, it is probably some kind of cache

Comment: yea I have eaccelerator installed, but how come it is not caching wordpress php files, but caches the random.php, the are in the same folder.

Comment: @JayChen what is the address of this random.php?

Comment: Is the page being cached in the browser?

Comment: @Lashane /theme/theme-name/random.php, alone with all other theme files

Comment: @JayChen why do you think that number is always the same? how do you check it?

Comment: @Lashane I ran the file, and $ran_num is always 7078, I am looking into cache now, maybe the issue is caused by eaccelerator

Comment: @JayChen try to add `echo rand();` along with mt_rand

Comment: @Lashane I think it is the php caching on my server, because I uploaded the new random.php to just do the Echo echo rand(); and nothing else, but it is still redirecting me to other page, which is what the old version of random.php is doing.

Comment: @JayChen I suppose it is browser's cache, not the server's one

Comment: @Lashane thank you for help, I got it fixed by creating a custom wordpress template.

Answer (score 0):

By default modern PHP creates different number for [`mt_rand`](http://php.net/mt_rand) (it's uses libc random number generator), so the problem can be somewhere else.

This can likely to be caused by some caching, for example check the followings:

- clear your web browser caching (use private mode or use different browser),
- disable Varnish (if it's in use),
- check whether code is using memory caching like Memcached/Redis,
- this may be related to PHP cache accelerators (but less likely),
- restart your web server just in case (could be some extra caching module),
- make sure you're editing the right file and it was deployed properly,
- test it in the smallest possible PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress may use cache, and if you reload the page, it loads from cache, so you will see the same random number again and again. It has nothing to do with PHP version in this particular case - to fix this, it is needed to disable the wordpress cache.